# WinXP Pro, 32bit. How change GS register

Tags: windows, segment

I have a code in OllyDBG:

```
MOV DWORD PTR GS:[396FF4],EBX
```

But OllyDBG shows:

```
EBX=00000B07
GS:[00396FF4]=???
```

So how is calculated final address to which EBX will be written?
I have free memory at address $004B0000. What I should put to code instead of $396FF4 to make EBX is written e.g. to address $004B0000.

Comment: It's simply `GS + 0x00396FF4`. `GS` will tend to be variable, so it's pretty unlikely you'll be able to use it in a meaningful way for your own purposes. Are you trying to crack some software?

Comment: I just see how assembler commands works. When GS=0 I can edit opcode like `MOV DWORD PTR GS:[004B0000],EBX`. But during step over opcode I get access violation when reading [FFFFFFFF] - use Shift+F7/F8/F9 to pass ecxeption to program. Section 004B0000 has write rights. Why I get AV?

Comment: Are you on Windows Vista+? What does [App verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) say? Also, how did you allocate that `004B0000` memory? And are you running a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system?

Comment: I am on Windows XP 32-bit (see title). Application is also 32-bit. But I just load dummy application in OllyDBG and write some assembler opcodes into entry point for learning. Memory $004B0000 is .data section of dummy application.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm confusing myself and you as well. On Windows, `GS` is actually the thread-local segment. You're on a protected system, so you can't just access memory directly, you're always working with virtual memory. I'm seriously mixing up stuff that doesn't apply, some from old-school real mode, some from old-school protected mode, some from Windows' mixed paging-segment system... I haven't done this in quite a while, and it seems like I forgot most of the stuff :) As far as I'm aware, you can't break out of the `GS` segment - it will always point to thread-local storage.

Comment: What about kernel mode? GS could be used by driver?

Comment: How do you mean "used by driver"? It's also used by user applications, otherwise you couldn't work with thread-local storage (and other thread information) - but it is an actual protected segment of memory, not one of the "fake" segments spanning the whole addressing space. And of course, each thread has it's own `GS` (that's why it's thread-*local*). Or do you mean something like manipulating the segment information itself?

Comment: > How do you mean "used by driver"?    If such code `MOV DWORD PTR GS:[396FF4],EBX` is driver's code, what it means? Driver can access to memory directly.

Comment: Do note that I misinformed about the way segment translation works earlier - it's actually a lot more complicated, with a segment descriptor table and such. The *actual* base address is not `GS`, but rather the base address specified in the segment descriptor table for the given segment.

Comment: Ah, that's one of the things I explained wrong earlier. `GS:[396FF4]` is a perfectly fine address if the (current) `GS` segment is big enough. The original code obviously used it - I'd guess it might actually be a thread's stack "segment" (it's pretty close to 4 MiB, which is the default stack size for the main thread; `4B0000` is beyond the 4 MiB, which would explain the access violation). In both cases, though, it has no relation whatsoever to the physical memory where it's located - it's still all paged memory.

Comment: So when you change `GS` to `0`, that's actually entirely fine - it just points to the null-segment descriptor. But you can't actually use that for addressing - that's when you get the segfault (or maybe GP or something like that, I'm not sure). To get the intended behaviour, you would intead have to point to a segment descriptor that has `0` as a base address, and enough length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for all the confusion. The real answer seems to be as follows:

On Windows (and other modern OS), the segmentation model is no longer used the same way as in old real-mode and protected-mode applications. Instead, the memory model is mostly "flat" (not segmented), with paging for easier management and protection. In fact, the x86-64 in 64-bit mode no longer even allows using segments any of the old ways.

The exception being `FS` and `GS` segments, which are intended for internal use by the OS. On Windows, the `GS` segment refers to the thread-local storage. As far as I'm aware, you can't break out of the segment - it's (hardware-) protected memory.

So your only way is to either change the segment (to one of those no longer used, like `DS` - it doesn't matter anymore which you choose, they all start at zero and cover the whole virtual memory you can ever use).

`MOV DWORD PTR DS:[4B0000], EBX` should work fine, as well as removing the segment register entirely (`MOV DWORD PTR [4B0000], EBX`).

Comment: I put to mem $004B0000 next bytes:`30 00 4B 00`. It is address $004B0030. But `MOV DWORD PTR GS:[4B0000],EBX` still gives AV. Note that `MOV DWORD PTR DS:[4B0030],EBX` works fine and writes EBX to $4B0030. Why?